# Getting ias working with ajax + pods in Wordpress

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress, jquery-ias

so I want to get Infinite Scroll (http://infiniteajaxscroll.com/) to work the HTML Part is:

```
 <div id="pagination">
<span class="pods-pagination-paginate ">
<span class="page-numbers current">1</span>
<a class="page-numbers" href="?action=search_speaker&amp;sort=AZ&amp;pg=2">2</a>
<a class="page-numbers" href="?action=search_speaker&amp;sort=AZ&amp;pg=3">3</a>
<a class="next page-numbers" href="?action=search_speaker&amp;sort=AZ&amp;pg=2">Next ›</a>
</span>
</div>
<div class="wrapper-pane clearfix">
<div class="pane"></div>
<div class="pane"></div>
<div class="pane"></div>
<div class="pane"></div>
</div>
```

The JS Code is:

```
   var ias = jQuery.ias({
 container: ".wrapper-pane",
 item: ".pane",
 pagination: ".pods-pagination-paginate",
 next: ".next a",
});
ias.extension(new IASTriggerExtension({offset: 2,text: 'Load more items'}));
ias.extension(new IASSpinnerExtension());  
ias.extension(new IASNoneLeftExtension({
  text: 'There are no more pages left to load.'
}));
```

So my Problem is that there is no Infinite Scroll. I tried to debug it a bit with .on('ready',function(){alert("its loaded");}); this worked fine after that I tried to get the same with scroll or next but these alerts wouldn't show up. So I think maybe the ias can't recognize the user scrolling? Is there a better way to debug ias?

Comment: Do you include all JS documents (not just the jquery-ias.js) in your HTML? Besides, I think debugging is more comfortable when using `console.log()` instead of `alert()`

Comment: with other JS documents you mean jQuery?

Comment: And other IAS (callback, extensions). I don't know whether you actually have to include them additionally, but if you didn't before, it could be worth a try.

Comment: na there are in as default if you include the jquery-ias.js . tried without them no luck either :/ tested the ias with the default posts from wordpress and the default navigation there and it works fine.. so I think maybe the Plugin doesn't work with the structure there... but I don't know what causes the error there.